# javascript-based code editor choice for existing Roslyn language lexer/parser

Tags: javascript, roslyn, codemirror

I've converted syntax parser part of [Roslyn project](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Parser) into javascript (Typescript) and it's worked, and now i want to find a javascript-based code editor which can integrate with Roslyn lexer/parser for highlighting

So far, I've found 2 editor:

With [ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/), looks like it only supports highlight with regular expression rules

With codemirror(_https://codemirror.net/), it does support if your lexer can be processed as a sream with state, but i dont know when/which parts of text codemirror will trigger lexer to reparsed as user typing (Roslyn parser already has mechanism to detect change, so i want to reuse it)

(Both ace editor, code mirror support mark text,but i'm not sure if it's good for perfomance, because you may have to clear marks before set a new mark again)

So how can i achieve this, any other code editor should I choose, any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror will re-run its mode on pieces of the document that are changed, you do not need your own change detection. Read [this blog post](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/codemirror-mode-system.html) for an explanation of CodeMirror modes.

Comment: thanks for answer, i've read all your those posts and modified runMode code in order to integrate with C# Roslyn parser, and so far so good.